# Apiary: Full URL on responses

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

My API return the full host URL, and in Apiary every user has it's own private URL for the mock server.

There's a way to use this URL in the response body?

For now I'm using my own URL in the response body.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is now way to do that as responses are statically mocked up. It is planned as [the response templating](http://support.apiary.io/forums/120125-general/suggestions/3334210-allow-templating-in-responses), but there is no ETA yet.

Comment: I'm surprised that ticket has been open for two years with no progress. :(

Comment: @JBCP It is waiting for MSON to provide much better and flawless experience. MSON is going to be big :)

Comment: @JBCP The intro is [on the blog](http://blog.apiary.io/2014/10/10/Crafting-MSON/)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. After reading through the MSON documentation (https://github.com/apiaryio/mson), it's not clear how it actually solves this problem.

Comment: @JBCP Directly, it doesn't. However, it's a foundation that would enable that (as having structured information about the payload helps tremendously with introducing pairing between input and output). Stay tuned!